# RED5 Publisher demo error

Tags: red5, flashmedialiveencoder

When trying tu run an rtmp stream encoded through flash media encoder, the log in the publisher demo of RED5 gives the following messages and the video does not work. What is the issue here?

12:03:35:421 - Using Google Pepper Flash Player 11,6,602,180
12:03:41:827 - Connecting to rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo
12:03:43:870 - Asynchronous code error - ReferenceError: Error #1069
12:03:43:870 - NetConnection.Connect.Success
12:03:43:173 - Asynchronous code error - ReferenceError: Error #1069
12:03:43:312 - Asynchronous code error - ReferenceError: Error #1069
12:03:43:335 - Asynchronous code error - ArgumentError: Error #1063